# How find a object by ID in a JavaScript object which could have a variable structure?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to know what is the faster way to retrieve an object by its id, keeping in consideration that the structure where it is stored could be different.
Does any native function in JS for this operation?

#### Example 1

```
var source = {
    "page": [{
        "id": "1",
        "site": "",
        "items": [{
            "id": "2"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "anotherItem": [{
                "id": "4"
            }, {
                "id": "5"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "6"
    }]
};
```

#### Example 2

Structure could be completely different, the script should be always able to get the object containing `id`.

```
{
    "smtElse": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry again: what is the question exactly?

Comment: You would have to traverse the object I suppose...

Comment: I need an algorithm which can find any object with id=x parsing a json without knowing its structure in advance. Sorry guys if my question is not really clear :)

Comment: you will have to recurse over all properties and return null or object when object contains the property id with your search value

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig thanks, does js have some native function for that? I to find out the faster possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: The algorithm is "look through the object till you find it." Also, why are you worried about speed before you even have figured out how to do it in the first place? Finally, `{ smtElse: ...}` is the not object containing ID, `{ id: ` ...}` is. Do you actually mean an object containing an object containing an ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no native function.

The fastest way is the same as the only way which is to iterate over the object, probably recursively, looking for IDs and returning what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following script, as it seems no native functionality is available.

```
var data = {
    item: [
        {
            itemNested: [
                {
                    itemNested2: [{
                        id: "2"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function findById(obj, id) {
    var result;
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.id == id) {
            return obj;
        } else {
            if (typeof obj[p] === 'object') {
                result = findById(obj[p], id);
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}


var result = findById(data, "2");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can try this
<script type="text/javascript">
var re = /"id":\s+"(.*?)"/;
var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
var results = [];
var i = 0;
for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
results[i] = matches;
for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
  alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
 }
 i++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't believe that someone actually posted a regexp solution to this. Sure that will also pick out the IDs, but how does it know what object they're part of?